# How to send any amount of emails? My own server or third party service?

Tags: email, server

I am working on a project where I want to allow my clients send a large amount of emails at any given time.

The issue I am having is that usually hosts have a very limited amount of emails allowed to send.
At the moment I am using third party service called `Mailgun` and it works fine but it is rather expensive since I have to send up to 300 000 emails per months and the number is growing.

Even if I rent a virtual server for example on scaleway where I have to set everything up myself, they have limitations.
Or are those limitations if I use their smtp?

Can anyone clear this one for me?

So my questions are:

Can I create my own smtp or any other way to send emails?

Is it possible to set up my own server and email server and send emails without any limitations? 
If yes can you give me a tutorial or a course on that?

Or is it too much of a headache to do it myself and I should stick to third party services?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SMTP is not a headache but IP reputation management is. That's why most hosting providers limit SMTP usage and third party services florish.

As for the question "should I stick to third party ?", there is no right answer possible, only opinions:

- If your emails are information requested by users (like forgot my password stuff, or notifications) you could use your own servers, because your IP reputation is going to be good.
- If you send marketing stuff, all I can say is that my biggest customers all rely on third party services. Probably for good reasons